# How to authorize device for adb when the touch control is completely broken?

Tags: adb, touchscreen, authorization

My Nexus 7 2012 has fallen from a table and though the display as well as the device itself is fine, the touch control is completely broken.  You cannot tap or touch anything.

I believe I can manage a restricted access to it (thanks to great tutorial: http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/1r2zha/how_i_managed_to_use_my_android_device_with_a) if only I can execute `adb` commands.

Unfortunately any attempts end with simple:

```
$ adb shell
error: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.
```

Which is no option for me as my touch control is gone :-(.

I am looking for any option how to bypass/authorize the confirmation without using the device's touchscreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what version of Android you have, but you should be able to connect a microUSB OTG cable with any old USB mouse to the Nexus and get control of the cursor. You can then click with the mouse in place of touch controls.

Comment: Stupid of me, that I did not realize that.  Saved my day.  Thanks a lot.